# WCF-ServiceReference Response gives ArrayOfXElement instead of the object

Tags: c#, wcf, xaml, windows-8.1, service-reference

I am trying to write login app.

My problem is that Service gives me ArrayOfXElement instead of an object.
And I do not know how to get to this object.

Here is the code:

StartPage.xaml.cs

```
using (...);

namespace MyFirstProject
{
public sealed partial class StartPage : Page
{
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client MyService;

    public StartPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MyService = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.GetSinglePassCmdResponse h = MyService.GetSinglePassCmdAsync(new ServiceReference1.Pass { nickName = tBoxNick_log.Text }).Result;
```

Now I thought that in h I have object and I can do smth like this:

```
testBlock.Text = "nickname: " + h.nickname + " password: " + h.pass;
    }}}
```

but I got error that GetSinglePassCmdResponse does not contain a definition for 'nickname'

IService1.cs

```
[OperationContract]
    Pass GetSinglePassCmd(Pass Pass);

[DataContract]
public partial class Pass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string nickName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string password { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> lastLogDate { get; set; }
```

Service1.svc

```
 public Pass GetSinglePassCmd(Pass Pass)
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Passwords WHERE nickName=@nickName", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nickName", Passwords.nickName);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Pass pass = new Pass();
        int i = 0;
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //assign dataset values to array
            pass.nickName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["nickName"].ToString();
            pass.password = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["password"].ToString();
            pass.lastLogDate = DateTime.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["lastLogDate"].ToString());

        }
        else pass = null;
        return pass;
    }
```

And in MyFirstProject->ServiceReferences->ServiceReference1->Reference.cs->GetSinglePassCmdResponse  I got

```
public partial class GetSinglePassCmdResponse {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public MyFirstProject.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfXElement GetSinglePassCmdResult;

    public GetSinglePassCmdResponse() {
    }

    public GetSinglePassCmdResponse(MyFirstProject.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfXElement GetSinglePassCmdResult) {
        this.GetSinglePassCmdResult = GetSinglePassCmdResult;
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me please... ?

PS I have also tried this:

```
testBlock.Text = "nickname: " + h.GetSinglePassCmdResult.nickname + " password: " + h.GetSinglePassCmdResult.pass;
```

Comment: Listen, I tried to read your question, first thing that strikes as problematic is that you add a lot of frankly unnecessary data, it doesn't matter how your page looks, just your WCF if the reference is the issue.  Also, why did you add .Result to the end of the WCF call? WCF call doesn't require that.  another issue, where is the service interface? every wcf service should have IService.cs file with it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
Sorry if I wrote wrong, I am newbie :)

I put WCF
IService1.cs (it`s the 2nd code)(Here is Service Interface you are asking for)

Service1.svc (3rd code)

and
StartPage.xaml.cs (1st - where I use the reference)

GetSinglePassCmdResponse to show that it is ArrayOfXElement as result not the object

What more should I write ?

If I delete .Result I got error: 
    Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type System.Threading.Tasks.Task<MyFirstProject.ServiceReference1.GetSinglePassCmdResponse>' to 'MyFirstProject.ServiceReference1.GetSinglePassCmdResponse'

Comment: Okay, I understand, have you tried to debug whatever is going on in the service side of things?  before it returns the result, does it perform things as expected?  If so, the only problem I can think of is that the service is not configured properly, I'd recommend you visit a guide to build the most basic of WCF service and host pairing, and try a hello world function and see if you get a response from it.

Comment: A good one to start with: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/566691/WCF-From-a-Beginners-perspective-a-Tutorial